# Can't write some unicode characters to file

Tags: r, windows, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Let's consider the following code:

```
> cat('\u2077\u2078\u2079 \u2087\u2088\u2089')
⁷⁸⁹ ₇₈₉
> out <- file("out.txt", "w", encoding = 'utf-8')
> cat('\u2077\u2078\u2079 \u2087\u2088\u2089', file=out)
> close(out)
```

the content of `out.txt` is:

```
78<U+2079> 789
```

The sub/superscript form is lost  and for exponent 9 it's the codepoint that is printed.

What's happening here? How can I have the correct form of the characters in the file as they are printed in the RStudio console?

Versions: RStudio 1.1.436 / R 3.5.2 / Windows 10

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is a dup, but I can't find it.  The issue is that R switches to the local encoding before converting to the requested one, and those characters don't exist there:  so get mangled.  One solution is to make sure the string is UTF-8 (it should be since you used `\u`), but declare it as "unknown", so it won't be translated on output.  Then you don't need to declare the encoding of the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aargh, windows and UTF-8!

I've been puzzling as well, and this works for me

```
options(encoding='native.enc')
out <- file('out.txt', open='w', encoding = 'UTF-8')
writeLines('\u2077\u2078\u2079 \u2087\u2088\u2089', 'out.txt', useBytes = TRUE)
close(out)
readback <- readLines('out.txt', encoding='UTF-8')
```

My setup is a bit older (my most used setup is OSX): Rstudio 0.99.903/R 3.3.1/Windows 7

The very strangest thing I've encountered is that it **stops** working if you set `options(encoding='UTF-8')`

And finally, I noticed all mentions of UTF-8 are in uppercase, I see you used lowercase, I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: The example code opens a connection to `"out.txt"` but the call to `writeLines()` does not use the connection, which does not make sense. If the connection was actually used, I would suggest using `encoding = ""` or `encoding = "native.enc"` as an argument to `file()` to bypass character encoding translation.

Comment: I know it does not make sense, and this is not the way it SHOULD be written. I just know that every "logical" solution I tried didn't work, and this does.

Comment: Looks like the winning combo is `options(encoding='native.enc')` and `useBytes = TRUE`.